# How do I inject username into footer?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to interject a username into the footer of a discord embedded message, that says who requested the command and I've tried varies things and I cant get it to work the way I want it to. Any help would be appreciated. I want it to go into the `price` command

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    username = ctx.message.author.display_name
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    await client.send_typing(channel)
    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Pong at {username}".format(username=username), description='It took {}ms.'.format(round((t2-t1)*1000)), color=0xDA70D6)
    await client.say(embed=embed) 
@client.command(aliases= ['price', 'p'])
    async def calc(quantity: int, itemA: str, itemB: str):
        #itemAPrice = get_value(itemA)
        #itemBPrice = get_value(itemB)
        itemAPrice = items[aliases[itemA]]
        itemBPrice = items[aliases[itemB]]
        if itemAPrice and itemBPrice:
            itemQuotient = itemAPrice/itemBPrice
            itemBEquivalent = round(quantity * itemQuotient, 2)
            embed=discord.Embed(title="Exchange Rate", description='{quantity} {itemA} is equal to {itemBEquivalent} {itemB}'.format(quantity = quantity, itemA = itemA, itemBEquivalent = itemBEquivalent, itemB = itemB), color=0xDA70D6)
            await client.say(embed=embed)
        elif not itemAPrice:
            await client.say('No match found for ' + itemA)
        elif not itemBPrice:
            await client.say('No match found for ' + itemB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the invocation context into the command, then use that to get the name of the user who invoked the command.  From there, you can use `ctx.message.author.name`, and insert that in your footer:

```
@client.command(aliases= ['price', 'p'], pass_context=True)
async def calc(ctx, quantity: int, itemA: str, itemB: str):
    itemAPrice = items[aliases[itemA]]
    itemBPrice = items[aliases[itemB]]
    if itemAPrice and itemBPrice:
        itemQuotient = itemAPrice/itemBPrice
        itemBEquivalent = round(quantity * itemQuotient, 2)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Exchange Rate", description='{quantity} {itemA} is equal to {itemBEquivalent} {itemB}'.format(quantity = quantity, itemA = itemA, itemBEquivalent = itemBEquivalent, itemB = itemB), color=0xDA70D6)
        embed.set_footer(text="Command invoked by {}".format(ctx.message.author.name))
        await client.say(embed=embed)
    elif not itemAPrice:
        await client.say('No match found for ' + itemA)
    elif not itemBPrice:
        await client.say('No match found for ' + itemB)
```

If you want to mention the user, you can use `ctx.message.author.mention` instead

Comment: raise BadArgument('Converting to "{0.__name__}" failed.'.format(converter)) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "int" failed.


I dont think its possible, see my answer below. What you posted was pretty much my original idea @Patrick Haugh

Comment: @giveen I forgot to include the `pass_context=True`.  You say you can't inject the username because the `set_footer` method accepts text, but a username is text.

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: set_footer() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: It needs `text` to be given as a keyword argument.  Try `embed.set_footer(text="Command invoked by {}".format(ctx.message.author.name))`

Comment: Thank you, so much. I did indeed forgot the text=

I've been struggling with this line for 3 days now. @Patrick Haugh

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't, only text and icon are supported
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.set_footer